# Pug interceptor failed: Error: The scheme has been intercepted

Tags: pug, electron, electron-forge

I have created an `Electron` app using `electron-forge`.
In this app I want to render `pug(Jade)` templates so I installed `electron-pug`. The problem I face is the following.

If I start my app using `electron-forge start` my app will show a window with the unrendered pug file(it will just shows the content of that file)
and it will log the following:

```
Pug interceptor failed: Error: The scheme has been intercepted
```

However If I run with `electron src/index.js` the pug template will render without a problem.
Here is my `index.js` file:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const pug = require('electron-pug')({pretty:true},{});
// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;
const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/demo.pug`);
  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
};
// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

And here is `index.pug`:

```
doctype
html
    head
        title Nope
    body
        h1 Hello
        p  
        | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
```

Any Ideas why this is happening

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you 6 months later, I've found no solutions; except to not use electron-forge. Electron's documentation recommends 3 build/packaging tools, of which electron-forge is one, so just switch to one of the other two.

Comment: @EvanThompson Electron-forge supports jade so I renamed all pug files to jade and everything is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this problem here is what I did:

Electron-Forge supports jade templating so I just renamed all my pug files to jade and it worked like a charm